# jQuery ajaxPrefilter fires after request is sent

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-3

According to the description of [jQuery.ajaxPrefilter()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/), it's supposed to get fired before the request is sent to `$.ajax()`, but from what I'm seeing in my project, the server API endpoint gets called first, then the `ajaxPrefilter` function is called at which point it's too late to make any changes.

I'm probably missing something here, but I don't see it...

Here's what my registration looks like:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (options.url.startsWith('api') || options.url.startsWith('/api')) {

        if (options.headers === undefined) {
            options.headers = {};
        }

        if (!options.headers.Authorization) {
            var jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
        }
    }
});
```

I'm fully aware that I can use `beforeSend` to set the headers, but I wanted to do it by first checking if the header exists, and if not, then add it, and the only way to read request headers before they're sent is only by using the `ajaxPrefilter` as far as I understand.

I might just end up using `beforeSend`, but I got curious as to why this doesn't work the way it's described in the documentation? Maybe I'm not fully understanding how this works...

I'm using jQuery version 3.3.1.

**EDIT:**

It seems like setting `async: false` fixes the problem, but that looks like a bug to me in jQuery.

**EDIT 2:**

I think I may have had some bug somewhere, because now the code above works. I have no idea where this bug could have been because it's not obvious at all by looking at my git changes, but it works for now...

Answer (score 0):

This way should work (in `$.ajaxPrefilter`, within your condition):

```
options.beforeSend = function (xhr) { 
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
}
```

However, I'm not exactly sure why you can't just set them to `jqXHR`, to be honest. That would seem logical to me as well.

Your code becomes:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
  if (options.url.startsWith('api') || options.url.startsWith('/api')) {

    if (options.headers === undefined) {
      options.headers = {};
    }

    if (!options.headers.Authorization) {
      var jwt = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
      options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where are you using `$.ajaxPrefilter`? also the reason I wanted to use it originally was to first check if the request headers contained the Authorization token, if not, then to add it. I don't need to use prefilter, but I'm curious as to why it's not working as advertised.

Comment: The code from this answer simply replaces `jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);` from your original post, within `$.ajaxPrefilter`. I'm aware I didn't help in actually explaining why altering `jqXHR` itself (at least its headers) isn't having any effect, though.

Comment: Oh right, it's so late I can't even read... Indeed it doesn't help because at the point of setting the headers the request has already reached the server which defeats the purpose of setting the headers in the first place :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This *does* change the headers before the requests are made, contrary to the code from the opening post. I might have misunderstood something though :)

Comment: I've edited my answer, just in case it makes it clearer.

Comment: This is so strange, your code works, and after I tried my own old code, and that works too. I probably had some really weird bug somewhere that I accidentally fixed... I think it's time for bed now :-) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Maybe you left `async: false`? :) Cause your code didn't seem to work for me either. Good night!

Comment: Oh, it didn't? I don't even know anymore.. I'll just keep the beforeSend to be safe and maybe investigate this later. I did remove the `async: false` for sure.